# Downgrade database from SQL Server 2012 to 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to downgrade the database to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition. I know there is no direct option. I tried to backup on 2012 and then restore on 2008. Not working.Any Idea on how to completely transfer database ?

Comment: You'll have to do either a lot of manual scripting (and running those scripts on your new downgraded server), or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Are you sure that I can convert sql server 2012 database file to sql server 2008 database using Red-Gate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare?

Comment: You can't *convert* a 2012 file to 2008 - you'll have to use the tools to generate and execute SQL scripts - but those tools will do this in a single step, and fully automatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **cannot *convert*** a SQL Server 2012 database file to a SQL Server 2008 database file. The downgrade is not possible. The compatibility of database files is available only from an old version to a newer one, not the opposite. Indeed, you **can *convert*** a SQL Server 2008 database file to SQL Server 2012 database file.

Use the integrated SQL Server tools:

1. Right click on the database.
2. Select `Tasks` and `Generate Scripts`.

Following the wizard, at the end of it in the `Advanced Scripting Options` clicking the "Advanced" button, select the SQL Server version for which you want to generate the scripts, using the option `Script for Server Version`. Moreover, you would be able to generate the scripts to export the schema of your objects and/or the data, selecting the option `Types of data to script`, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

The time needed for the process to generate both (schema and data) will depend on the amount of data you want to export, of course. As @Arun suggested, have a look at the process in more detail [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/), using step by step instructions.

Comment: This is the best way. For step by step instructions with pictures. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/

Comment: Just to understand. Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks @Arun. I was referring to some people that have the strange habitude of downvoting the answers/questions without explaining the reason.