# Can't attach database to SQL Server 2012 reason not found .log

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to attach the `AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf` database file to my SQL Server 2012 database.

I am getting this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server 'USER-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1322+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2012_log.ldf". Operating system error 2: "2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Maybe the message is clear that I don't have the `.log` file and yes I don't have it. But is it necessary to have it? Or is there is another thing? How can I solve that please?

Comment: Try via `sp_attach_single_file_db`

Comment: @AlexK. you mean execute that query in my sql server 2012 ?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174385.aspx

Comment: @AlexK. I tried this `sp_attach_single_file_db [ @dbname= ] 'AdventureWorks2012_Data'
    , [ @physname= ] 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ARPAD\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'` but I got this error: `Incorrect syntax near 'AdventureWorks2012_Data'.`

Comment: `exec sp_attach_single_file_db 'AdventureWorks2012_Data', 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ARPAD\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'`

Comment: @AlexK. I got this error `The database 'AdventureWorksDW2012' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'AdventureWorksDW2012'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common error that anyone could encounter when you don't have any `*.LDF` log file for your database, like the `AdventureWorks` database. SQL Server complains about the `*.LDF` log file (typically associated to a database `*.MDF` file) that is missing.
Execute the following T-SQL query to attach the database considering only the `*.MDF` file:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [AdventureWorksDW2012] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ARPAD\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

or remove the connection to the `*.LDF` log file (a new `*.LDF` file will be created for the database) through SQL Server Management Studio as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

You get the error:

```
The database 'AdventureWorksDW2012' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database 'AdventureWorksDW2012'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)
```

because you're trying to attach a SQL Server 2012 (version 706) database file to SQL Server 2008 istance (version 661). For this reason, you [cannot perform this downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103477/downgrade-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008/26104462#26104462). [Download the AdventureWorks2008](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/478218) database for your SQL Server 2008 istance instead, or upgrade your SQL Server istance with the latest version.

The version of your SQL Server istance is indeed SQL Server 2008: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`.
[Download and install SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) to solve the problem.

Comment: I got this error` The database 'AdventureWorksDW2012' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'AdventureWorksDW2012'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The error is now different. You're trying to attach a SQL Server 2012 (version 706) database to SQL Server 2008 istance (version 661). For this reason, you cannot perform this downgrade. Download the AdventureWorks2008 database for your SQL Server 2008 istance instead.

Comment: now I am using sql server 2012, but maybe by mistake I choose the setting of sql seerver 2008? I don't know. but I am using sql server 2012 not 2008

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The error is clear. You're trying to restore a 'newer' database file to an 'older' SQL Server istance.

Comment: really I am using sql server 2012. really really.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli What is the version of SQL Server Management Studio? Please remember that the version of SQL Server Management Studio could be different from the version of your SQL Server istance. Please execute this query: `SELECT @@VERSION;` and post the result here.

Comment: the result is `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) 
 Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)` though I am using sql server 2012, what should I do please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli As I was saying, you have a SQL Server 2008 engine, while you have a SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (the UI). You should update your SQL Server 2008 engine to SQL Server 2012. Consider the opportunity to [download and install SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) (it's free).

Comment: and installing that sql 2012 won't affect my job on the current 2008 r2 version?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli What do you mean by 'my job'? The databases that are currently installed won't be deleted, if you mean this.

Comment: when I tried to download from the link you gave to me, there are too many choices, which choices should I choose please? i am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Download the file `ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` that contains: "Express with Advanced Services (contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search)" Perform the update of your current SQL Server 2008 database engine.

Answer (score 2):

The key is this line (edited for clarity):

```
Unable to open the physical file 
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2012_log.ldf". 
  Operating system error 2: 
  "2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)". 
  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
```

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), operating system error 2 is "File Not Found".  Based on this, I would guess that either, A) the file is not there , or B) the name or path is misspelled.

Comment: but I am attaching through the windows UI of the sql managment studio when you right click on databases and choose attach

Comment: And you think that is not generating some SQL code? Hint - it does. everything you do in the UI is actually a statement sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm too slow the answer above is what I'm talking about)

FYI This answer assumes your using the attach a database dialog.

Make sure you've told sql manager where the ldf file is too.  It will fill in an entry for a log even if you aren't attaching the log with the mdf.

You'll see it in the box below the one with the add button.  You can just remove the log from the attach if you don't have it.  Sql will make a new log and you can move merrily along the way.