# Export and Restore Database

Tags: sql-server, database, umbraco

I've been working with Umbraco to create my first website and I'm now ready to upload it to the server. However I'm having a bit of trouble with the database. Im using MSSQLfor my database and need to export the data and upload it to my server. My question is: whats the proper way to export my database? Is it through the option "Export Data" or "Generate Script"? Because with "Export Data" I see no way to create the file and then upload it to the server.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a full backup, copy that over to your server, then restore the backup to your server.

Comment: You mean doing Tasks -> Back Up ... ?

Comment: Yep, take a full backup then restore this to the server

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error message stating: "Cannot show requested Dialog... VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.." Any idea of what this is? Thank you very much!

Comment: At this point you'd probably be better heading over to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

Try the SQL server import and export wizard for exporting database - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: But with export data option is not possible to create the file right? I want to create the .sql file and then upload it to the database server.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it through the option "Export Data" or "Generate Script"? Because
>   with "Export Data" I see no way to create the file and then upload it
>   to the server.

Using the "Export data" function, you can transfer your data (rows of a table) connecting your MSSQL instance to another or even generate an Excel file.

Using the "Generate script" function, you can instead generate the schema of your tables (and even database) and the related rows within them, exporting everything in a SQL file. Some time ago, I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104462/702048) to another SO question regarding the "Generate script" function. Obviously, the size of the script will depend on the amount of data you want to transfer.

In my opinion, it's not recommended to run a script file larger than 100 MB in the SQL Management Studio's editor, because the SQL Management Studio's editor could have issues handling such large files. In alternative, you can run the script using the [sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx) command line utility.

From what I've seen, you need to transfer your data and you can use both options. Otherwise, you can backup your database, transfer the BAK file to the server and restore there the database, but it seems you don't have permissions to do that.